# How do I assign button a different value depends on the button clicked in react

Tags: reactjs, frontend

I'm creating a component in react where the user is supposed to choose between six different buttons and then a when you check the button you can press the next button. I have seen some tutorials with radiobuttons, but not with ordinary buttons.
This is the prototype:
https://preview.uxpin.com/7fb204007fc97420378cd5c8e987a91e9a28d1bf#/pages/122748926?mode=i
Any tips or links for help?

Comment: Welcome. As such, your question does not fit here. Please read this carefully:https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking and write a clear question

Comment: How does this question not fit here? I am not violating any of the don't-ask rules and I am asking for help on a spesific problem

Comment: can you provide your sample code please ?

Comment: Your are asking for "tips". So do you have a problem or not ? Is so, please describe what it is, what you expect, and show the code. You also ask for "links", which is also not recommended, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2):

```
Tried this, but it doesn't seems to work for me.

let ratingValue = [{ val: 1 }, { val: 2 }, { val: 3 }, { val: 4 }, { val: 5 }, { val: 6 }];

class Scale extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleButtonClicked = this.handleButtonClicked.bind(this);
  }

  handleButtonClicked(buttonNumber, buttonValue) {
    console.log("User Pressed " + buttonNumber + "with Rating of " + buttonValue);
  }

  render() {
    let buttonsMap = ratingValue.map((button, index) => {
      return (
        <button key={index} onClick={this.handleButtonClicked(index, button.val)}>
          {button.val}
        </button>
      );
    });
    return <div>{buttonsMap}</div>;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let ratingValue = [{ val: 1 }, { val: 2 }, { val: 3 }, { val: 4 }, { val: 5 }, { val: 6 }];

class Scale extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.handleButtonClicked = this.handleButtonClicked.bind(this);
  this.state={
    selected_value:null
   }
}

handleButtonClicked(buttonNumber, buttonValue) {
 this.setState({selected_value:buttonValue});
 console.log("User Pressed " + buttonNumber + "with Rating of " + buttonValue);
}

render() {
const {selected_value}=this.state;
let buttonsMap = ratingValue.map((item, index) => {
//disable button which is pressed
  return (
    <button disabled={item.val==selected_value} key={index} onClick={()=>{this.handleButtonClicked(index, item.val)}}>
      {item.val}
    </button>
  );
});
return <div>
{buttonsMap}
//disable button if not button is pressed
<button disabled={!selected_value} >Next</button> 

</div>;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got a error message saying:
 "× Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. "

Comment: Oh sorry. You cannot call function directly to onClick method. Replace onClick={this.handleButtonClicked(index, item.val)} with onClick={()=>{this.handleButtonClicked(index, item.val)}}

Comment: Thank you so much! Highly appreciated!